# How can I turn a user input into a global function? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, global, raw-input

I'm trying to create my own text game, as instructed in Ex 45 of Learning Python the Hard Way, but I'm a bit stuck. I have my own inventory system set up and I need to figure out how to display a list of the inventory any time the user types "inventory" (I also want to do similar things for "help")... I know that I could add an if-statement after every raw_input for it, but I wanted to see if there was some global function or code that I could use to make this a lot easier on me.

I've searched and searched but I have no idea how to phrase the question or what I could possibly do to fix this. Here's my inventory set-up, with how I'm using to call it:

```
class Item(object):
 def __init__(self, name, quantity=1):
    self.name = name
    self.raw = name.strip().lower()
    self.quantity = quantity

 def recalc(self):
    self.netValue = self.quantity * self.value

class Container(object):
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.inside = {}

 def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.inside.items())

 def __len__(self):
    return len(self.inside)

 def __contains__(self, item):
    return item.raw in self.inside

 def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.inside[item.raw]

 def __setitem__(self, item, value):
    self.inside[item.raw] = value
    return self[item]

 def add(self, item, quantity=1):
    if quantity < 0:
        print "ERROR."
    if item in self:
        self[item].quantity += quantity
        self[item].recalc()
    else:
        self[item] = item           

inventory = Container("Inventory")
```

And here's what I'm using to call it when inventory is typed:

```
print "Inventory: [" + ",".join((item[1].name for item in inventory)) + "]"
```

Comment: So as I see it, you have implemented your inventory system, and you have figured out how to print the contents of the inventory. What you have problems with is figuring out when the user types "inventory". Is that correct? If that is the case, the code you use for handling user input will be more relevant than the inventory system code.

Comment: You are correct! I guess the inventory part wasn't completely needed.

When I get to user input, I'm using raw_input() to handle what they type, and then implementing if-statements to continue the story. So if they type "shoot" I would have an if-statement for shoot, and another for, say, "dodge".

I want them to be able to type "inventory" at any time during the game and have it display their inventory to that point.

Comment: eval() will work (strip well the string) but is unsafe. The user may type sys.exit or else. A way to sanitize this is to put method in a class (maybe override __getattr__ ) and eval only in the context of that class

Comment: I'm a fan of the `cmd` module for these sorts of games. You can inherit from `cmd.Cmd` and add your own methods, such as `myCmd.do_inventory`. When a player types `inventory`, the method is invoked automatically. If the string is longer, the first word is removed and the rest are sent to the method as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a dictionary combined with lambdas, this would be compact and fast

```
from __future__ import print_function

#store commands
inputLookup = {"Inventory" : lambda: print ("Inventory: [" + ",".join((item[1].name for item in inventory)) + "]"), "other text" : lambda: 3} #and so on

text = input() #replace with hover you get input
inputLookup[text]()  # call the function from dictionary at that command
```

the import will change all your print statements to a print() however.
For lambdas you can also do.

```
def f():
    print "Inventory: [" + ",".join((item[1].name for item in inventory)) + "]"

inputLookup = {"Inventory": lambda: f()}
text = input()
try:
    inputLookup[text]
except:
    print "that is not a valid input" #or something
```

this will allow you to use the old print statment

---

yes, you should never use recursion to the same function in this manner, you'll generate a large stack. Also, those print statements are in a weird place.

```
def func1():
    print "Uh oh."
    print "You're outside the house and it's quiet."
    print "You EXAMINE and find a ROCK."
    While True:
        userinput1 = raw_input(">>> ")
        if userinput1 == "inventory":
            print "Inventory: [" + ",".join((item[1].name for item in inventory)) + "]"
        elif userinput1 == "pick up": 
            if rock not in inventory:       # so they can't pick up infinite rocks   
                inventory.add(rock)
                print "You picked up a ROCK."
            else:
                print "you've already picked up the rock"
        elif userinput1 == "examine":
            print "Man's best friend."
        else:
            print "Let's go on about our way then."
            break
```

I failed to see you were just starting out. I would stay away from lambda's for the moment, as they're a bit more advanced, sorry for the confusion. Before, if you look at your if/elif/else tree, there was no way for the else statement to be called, so i've edited it a bit, i hope it functions the way you intended. Also, are inventory and rock globals? if not you would need to declare or reference them in the function. (although as a future note, staying a way from globals is generally good)

---

hmm...i assume you mean items like the rock and such.

```
Items = {'rock': Rock(), 'item2': Item2(), 'item3' : item3()} #where Item() is creating the object
Inventory.add(Items[itemname]) # adds the item
```

You could make Items as a global so you can access it everywhere. This is ok for now, but as you learn, you should generally stay away from globals.

Comment: I keep getting a Syntax Error with this, showing up past the dict.

Comment: Okay, it's showing that the syntax error is on the word print, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: o, sorry, i made this in python 3, where you use brackets around the print statement. I converted it to 2, but apparently it doesn't work the same. see the edited code, as it requires an import and some brackets

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Looks like I cleared that up. Does that mean for every iteration of 'print' that I use, I'll need to use parentheses?

Comment: Great!! Your second box of code is working for me. Last question, I swear--- For "inputLookup[...]()" would I need to place this in every instance of user input? Or could I replace [...] with something so that I wouldn't have to?

Comment: hmmm...not sure if i understand. Are you asking if you need to do inputLookup["Inventory"]() then inputLookup["Some other input"] and some on? no, just store the input into a variable like i've done above, say text, then call inputLookup[text](). you should also put a try catch. i'll edit to show you

Comment: I'm getting in way too deep here; I'm so confused. I would hate to waste more of your time... Thank you for your help thus far though!!

Comment: well, i don't mind helping you if something's not clear. But if you'd like to take it from here, maybe read the dictionary and lambda pages in the python doc. it might help clear things up for you. If you question was putting this code at every input, just replace the input call with a function that gets the input and does a lookup in the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, here's the sample code I've been working with to (try) to get this right: http://pastebin.com/AsuhxBnW ..... Now I need to loop this function to repeat itself if the user input isn't equal to anything I have set; the way this is typed out, it returns 'global function not defined.... I'm assuming I need a while loop? I am so confused. Thank you so much for your help though.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you SO much! This clears everything up. I have my little example file running very smoothly now, all thanks to you! Last question, promise this time! - What would be the cleanest, most efficient way to write a dict for the items that will be pick-up-able? As it stands, I would just be writing different items in the main code and that doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function for each valid user input, such as inventory

Then, you could do:

```
input = raw_input('...')
self.method = getattr(<your class>, input)
self.method()
```

which would call

```
def inventory(self, ...):
    pass
```

Comment: Excuse me for having to ask for further explanation (I'm really new at this), but how would a function for each input look? (Also, where you have <your class>, what would I call for the class? Inventory or Container?)

Comment: @mutt Sorry, I missed this reply. getattr() would grab the function you've specified from that class. So if the function is part of Inventory, use Inventory.